# ionic 2 check internet connection not working

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

I want to check internet connection. I try this code but return nothing to me.

```
ionViewDidEnter() {
  this.network.onConnect().subscribe(data => {
    console.log(data)
  }, error => console.error(error));

  this.network.onDisconnect().subscribe(data => {
    console.log(data)
  }, error => console.error(error));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I try this code but return nothing to me.

Check the [Ionic Native Docs](http://ionicframework.com/docs/native/network/)
Both `onConnect` and `onDisconnect` return an observable to be subscribed to know *when* the event occurs.

There is no data *type* returned.

Just do:

```
 this.network.onConnect().subscribe(() => {
    console.log("Connected successfully")         
    //do other tasks after connected
  }, error => console.error(error));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be Ok.

But you should wait for `Platform.ready()` promise, it means that cordova is ready.

```
constructor(public platform: Platform, public network: Network)
```

Then:

```
ionViewDidEnter() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
        this.network.onConnect().subscribe(data => {
            console.log(data)
        }, error => console.error(error));

        this.network.onDisconnect().subscribe(data => {
            console.log(data)
        }, error => console.error(error));
   });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing'll not return the connection type or if it's connected or not. This'll just create observables on your connection so if you disconnect or connect it'll execute a function.

If you want to check if you're connected use `this.network.type`

```
ionViewDidEnter() {
  console.log(this.network.type);
}
```

This'll return a string with the type of your connection, it can be `WIFI`, `NONE`, and others.

So if you want to check your connection and then do something if it's disconnect just do

```
ionViewDidEnter() {
  if(this.network.type == 'NONE'){
    // EXECUTE SOMETHING
  }
}
```

Hope this helps